# Error : Unable to start the zeroconf: Permission denied

Tags: keyboard, mouse, connection-sharing

I am trying to use Barrier-kvm for sharing Keyboard and mouse but can't start it. I'm getting this error.

**Zero Configuration service**
Unable to start the zeroconf: Permission denied.

Comment: What command are you running? Is this the only output?

Comment: I downloaded barrier-kvm from the Ubuntu Store. When I launch it, and select the server option, I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions issue regarding installation with Ubuntu app store the fix is to reinstall with command-line permissions.

```
$ sudo apt install rclone barrier
```

Comment: Why is this installing a package called `rclone`?

Comment: @nobar: It is because... the command says to install it. The reason you want to is because it triggers a dependency that barrier needs (libavahi-compat-libdnssd1).

Answer (score 0):

I had installed on `18.04` using `snap` and saw that error on startup.

I resolved this by disabling all security confinement -- reinstalling with...

```
snap install --devmode barrier-kvm
```

*Installing KVM software implies a certain level of trust.*

---

Another clue for me was that the setup screen said:

```
IP addresses: unknown
```

Comment: ...or you can try building from source: https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/wiki

Comment: ...although, when trying to build from source on 18.04, I ran into `Missing library: Xtst` -- which hasn't had an obvious solution for me.

Comment: The build worked on 18.10, where barrier is already in the apt repository.

Comment: This install approach is currently broken on 18.04: https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/231

Comment: ... and there doesn't seem to be an older channel available.  Boo `snap`.  `sudo snap install barrier-kvm --devmode --channel 2.1.1/stable`

Comment: The issue '231' has been fixed on GitHub (see that thread).  I was able to install using the "flatpak" approach described therein.

Comment: I couldn't find the instructions that I indicated above.  Generic instructions here: http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html

Answer (score 0):

> - **Use a Devmode ::** 
>     *as advised already by @nobar above*

```
# *** Warning! ***
# *** Below snap install drops all Security Confinements! ***
# ** USE AT YOUR OWN RISK! ** 
# ===========================

sudo snap install --devmode barrier-kvm
```

> > **Try** Barrier **Beta Snap** -- as it uses a different build options::

```
sudo snap install barrier-kvm --beta
```

> > > Third option ::  **Build your own Snap!**

- source yaml file merged in official Barrier's Git repo
- https://github.com/debauchee/barrier

*To build a snap might be also pain in the a$$... 
Same issues as with Flatpak and/or building from source ;)*